# How to show the distance relative to the user's location?

Tags: 8, location

I'm trying to recreate a site, and one part of the content is supposed to show the distance relative to the user's location, like this:

[image]

Does anyone know of a way I can accomplish this?

Comment: any advance with the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the [Geolocation Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/geolocation) module and the example submodule that comes with it.

In the examples you will find a view that made exactly what you need, and you only will need to clone and edit the view.

> Geolocation Field provides a field type to store geographical
>   locations as pairs of latitude and longitude (lan,lng). The Drupal 8
>   version also provides a views proximity search plugin. Geolocation
>   Field can be used with all fieldable entities like nodes, users,
>   comments, taxonomy terms, etc.